# Pipe output of jack_cpu_load through sed

Tags: shell-script, jack, dsp

In the shell, when I pipe `jack_cpu_load` through `sed`, or `cut`, no matter what options I use it stops printing just before the lines I want to see.

`jack_cpu_load | sed -n 8p` will print:

```
Jack: JackClient::kActivateClient name = jack_cpu_load ref = 4
```

The very next line should read something like `jack DSP load 0.294772` which is what I'm looking for, but when I run `jack_cpu_load | sed -n 9p` which should print that line, there is nothing. Just a cursor, until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and kill it.

Unfortunately there is very little documentation on this command and I'm just a user, a musician no less, trying to hack together something that will let me see the dsp load at a glance in my status bar.

Terminal Output:

```
tony@hydra ~ $ jack_cpu_load
Jack: JackClient::SetupDriverSync driver sem in flush mode
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Connect name = jack_sem.1000_default_jack_cpu_load
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Connect sem_getvalue 0
Jack: Clock source : system clock via clock_gettime
Jack: JackLibClient::Open name = jack_cpu_load refnum = 4
Jack: JackClient::Activate
Jack: JackClient::ClientNotify ref = 4 name = jack_cpu_load notify = 2
Jack: JackClient::kActivateClient name = jack_cpu_load ref = 4 
jack DSP load 0.163633
jack DSP load 0.159914
jack DSP load 0.159449
jack DSP load 0.164087
jack DSP load 0.159971
^CJack: jack_client_close
```

For this:

```
tony@hydra ~ $ jack_cpu_load 2>&1 | sed -n 8p
Jack: JackClient::kActivateClient name = jack_cpu_load ref = 4
```

And for this:

```
tony@hydra ~ $ jack_cpu_load 2>&1 | sed -n 9p
```

There's nothing.

The output for strace -f jack_cpu_load http://justpaste.it/e7st

Comment: Maybe the output doesn't all go to stdout. Try `jack_cpu_load 2>&1 | sed -n 8p`. Does that help? If not can you fully copy what happens in your terminal please

Comment: I keep thinking that's what's going on but no, 2>&1 doesn't change anything. I added terminal output to the OP.

Comment: Maybe it starts something in the background which outputs the other stuff... Here probably only using `strace` will shed light on what's going on. (`strace -f jack.....`)

Comment: I added a link to a file with the output. I see three pids, but beyond that I'm out of my depth. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Currently I don't understand either. You see they all write to fd1 (stdout). You see it more clearly when you run `strace -f -t -e trace=write jack_cpu_load`. So no idea why you can't catch anything beyond the 8th line. What happens when you redirect to a file? (`jack_cpu_load > bla.txt`, wait for a while, then Ctrl-C, then inspect the file)

Comment: It's the same output that shows on the terminal. I'm going to ask the developer about it. I guess I should have started there, but I thought the problem was something obvious that I'm just not aware of, thanks!

Comment: Then it can only be a buffering issue. Try `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 jack_cpu_load | sed -n 9p`

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Now I have to get back to trying to understand how to use sed...

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer ;) Oh and feel free to create another question about sed or more generally about what you want to do with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the output doesn't all go to stdout. Try `jack_cpu_load 2>&1 | sed -n 8p`

Or it is a buffering issue. Try `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 jack_cpu_load | sed -n 9p`

Comment: Yes, buffering.