# Shell script too slow for output to Conky

Tags: shell-script, conky

I want the output of

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 jack_cpu_load | sed -n 's/[A-Za-z]*//g;s/ //g;s/.\{4\}$//;9,$p'
```

to be displayed in Conky but, I suspect, Conky is starting the script with every refresh and the script is too slow producing an output for anything to show.

Or, maybe it's something else entirely.

I used `${execp /path/to/script.sh}`

Is there a way to let the script run and for Conky to sample the output. Provided my theory is correct. *shrugs*

Edit: I'm working on sending the output to a file then having Conky read that, but I'm having a hard time getting it to overwrite the file.

The closest I've gotten so far is, `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 script.sh > file.log` but that just keeps appending the output to the file until I stop and start it again.

Comment: maybe look into the `mkfifo` command...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should say that this is related to [Pipe output of jack_cpu_load through sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110960/pipe-output-of-jack-cpu-load-through-sed)

So you wish to extract the float values from this output

```
jack DSP load 0.163633
jack DSP load 0.159914
jack DSP load 0.159449
jack DSP load 0.164087
jack DSP load 0.159971
```

Never heard of conky before. Looks cool.

**What I would do here:**

Do not call the executable each time but have jack_cpu_load write into a "circular buffer" (I multiply by 100 because I'm not sure what conky does to floats)

```
stdbuf -oL jack_cpu_load | grep --line-buffered "jack DSP load" | stdbuf -oL cut -d' ' -f4 | while read line; do echo "scale=0; $line*100/1" | bc -l > /tmp/buffer; done &
```

Read the buffer from conky:

```
${tail /tmp/buffer 1 1}
```

Or draw a bar

```
${execbar cat /tmp/buffer}
```

or

```
${execibar 1 cat /tmp/buffer}
```

I have no X here, but I'll let you try :)

PS. Also found this on stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427936/mpd-lua-conky) which shows other possibilities

Comment: This is very, very close to what I need. The only problem is that when this number really matters it is >1. I can probably figure it out from here though. Thank you very much!

Comment: Here's what I'm going with: stdbuf -oL jack_cpu_load | grep --line-buffered "jack DSP load" | stdbuf -oL cut -d' ' -f4 | stdbuf -oL sed -e 's/.\{4\}$//' > /tmp/buffer &

Comment: Just be careful that /tmp/buffer doesnt fill your disk when you dont go on a line per line basis, and that actually the last item is used by conky.

Comment: Okay. How's this: `stdbuf -oL jack_cpu_load | grep --line-buffered "jack DSP load" | stdbuf -oL cut -d' ' -f4 | while read line; do echo "$line*100/1" | stdbuf -oL sed -e 's/.\{10\}$//' > /tmp/buffer; done &` The output looks the way I want.

Comment: You left the $line*100 but no bc (calculator) anymore. I haven't tried but I wonder if the output really is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need `execpi` instead of `execp`

```
   execpi interval command
          Same as execp but with specific interval.  Interval can't be less than update_interval in configuration. Note that the output from the $execpi com‐
          mand is still parsed and evaluated at every interval.
```

Comment: Thanks. The output still isn't showing, but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: did you use the `interval` setting?

Comment: I tried `${execpi 6 /home/bin/dsp.sh}` and `${execpi 10 /home/bin/dsp.sh}` either should be plenty of time but no output.

Answer (score -1):

Try to giving more room for text with "text_buffer_size".

Comment: Questions to the OP should go in comments, which you can provide once you have enough reputation on this site. As it is (and since stdbuf has not text_buffer_size option), it is not clear to me how your answer could help the OP without further details.