# bc removes decimal point

Tags: shell-script, bc

This is related to [Shell script too slow for output to Conky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111050/shell-script-too-slow-for-output-to-conky)

This code is nearly perfect:

```
stdbuf -oL jack_cpu_load \
    | grep --line-buffered "jack DSP load" \
    | stdbuf -oL cut -d' ' -f4 \
    | while read line; do
        echo "scale=0; $line*100/1" | bc -l > /tmp/buffer
    done &
```

The only issue is that `bc` removes the decimal point and zero when the output is <1.

I'd like to see two places after the decimal point, but no fractions at all, with a zero for output <1 would be fine.

Comment: Can you give us just the output of `stdbuf...` without the `bc`?

Comment: The "divide by 1" operation looks useless.

Comment: Ouch! Why not just `stdbuf -oL jack_cpu_load | awk '/jack DSP load/{print $4*100}'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make it

```
stdbuf -oL jack_cpu_load |
grep --line-buffered "jack DSP load" |
stdbuf -oL cut -d' ' -f4 |
while read line; do echo "$line" > /tmp/buffer; done &
```

to output the value that you input without modification.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I just add my little sed bit to it and it's what I want. Thanks again.

Comment: What does `sed` do again in your case? Here we already have `cut` in place, which extracts the fourth part (the float) of the input.

Comment: I'm using `sed` to trim off the last four digits. Just to make it look better.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you just add the `scale=` so that it has a value higher than `0` you'll get decimal numbers displayed.

#### Example

```
$  echo "scale=0; 100*100/1" | bc -l
10000

$  echo "scale=2; 100*100/1" | bc -l
10000.00
```

#### Getting 44.93 and not 0.4493, why?

The use of `$line*100/1` with the `100/1` seems unnecessary. Take that bit out. Multiplying the `$line` by 100 is skewing your results by 2 decimal places.

Comment: I tried that, but the decimal point is in the wrong place, i.e. what should be 0.4493 shows as 44.93 and what I want is 0.44

Comment: @user57649 - that's b/c you're multiplying it by 100/1.